# Sign+Encrypt+Symmetric: Unable to specify Symmetric + Signing Key passphrases in single command

Tags: gnupg, gpg-agent

So I've been reading up on Symmetric and Asymmetric. However, according to the docs for GPG, you can actually use Encrypt + Sign + Symmetric in the same command, which allows for a person to decrypt the file with either a passphrase or their key.

The command I've been working with is:

```
gpg --symmetric --batch --yes --quiet --pinentry-mode loopback
--passphrase "MySymPassphrase" --armor --encrypt 
--recipient "email@domain.com" --cipher-algo AES256 
--sign --local-user ABCDEFAB 
--passphrase "PassphraseForSigning" -o my.gpg file.doc
```

In order to do this, that would mean I need to specify two passphrases, the symmetric passphrase, and also the passphrase for my own personal key when I sign.

However, in the code above, it only reads the last occurance of passphrase, and it has to be whatever the phrase is for the signature key. It won't let me define a symmetric passphrase as something different.

How is this supposed to be done to where it's all completely silent and I have to enter nothing

Looking for a way to specify both the symmetric passphrase, and whatever the passphrase is for the key to sign the file.

The windows program "Kleopatra" allows for this configuration, but I was looking for a command-line solution that doesn't need a GUI and can be automated.